# LINQ - How to Construct Query When the Column Name is not known until Runtime?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Given:

```
string metadata.XAxisColumn -- contains a column name (e.g., "Date")
string metadata.YAxisColumn -- contains another columnname (e.g., "Close")
```

When I know the names of the columns up front, of course I can do:

```
var query = from record in myView 
    where record.Date >= startDate && record.Date <= endDate
    select record.Close
```

However, the column names are not known until runtime. They're in `metadata.XAxisColumn` and `metadata.YAxisColumn`.

What is the correct way to construct a query that works like this:

```
var query = from record in myView 
    where record.[metadata.XAxisColumn] >= startDate && record.[metadata.XAxisColumn] <= endDate
    select record.[metadata.YAxisColumn]
```

Comment: What type are the objects (i.e. record)?

Comment: @Kieren - they're a generic type (which I suppose is part of the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use either ESQL/QueryBuilder (built in to EF) or Microsoft Dynamic Query (a.k.a. Dynamic LINQ -- free via VS Code Gallery).

Answer (score 1):

You could derive from the type of 'record' objects, and add a new property:

```
public class MyRecord : RecordBase
{
    public XAxis
    {
        get
        {
            switch (metadata.XAxisColumn)
            {
                // for example only; this code will not compile because it depends what kind of object RecordBase is :)
            case X:
                return this.X;
            case Y:
                return this.Y;        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I see where you're going with this, and although I really don't want to go there, it is very likely I'll end up doing something like this. (future code maintainability and all...)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) for those queries